# Trying to bind glide in Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, android-glide

I want to bind the library [`Glide`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) in Xamarin, but I am getting stuck on`com.bumptech.glide.BitmapOptions`.

As this is an interface, it binds to `IBitmapOptions`, but it can't find that name in that namespace. I have tried looking in the output folder, but that interface seems to have disappeared.

I looked at the other errors I am getting and the binding project can't find 2 other interfaces. I looked in the Java code, and I see it uses the `<?, ?, ?, ?>` generic syntax.

Is there some problem with this syntax that makes it so that it cannot be bound? If so, how do I solve this?

Comment: were you able to successfully create the binding library for glide?

Comment: @Syma, nope, we are now handling all image loading ourselves, but it still has issues performance-wise. We will probably be going back to Picasso.

Comment: To everyone, we are currently using FFImageLoader and are seeing very good results. This is definitely better than using Picasso. We still have not been able to bind and test the performance of Glide in Xamarin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glide for Xamarin binding on Github:  https://github.com/thanhdatbkhn/Glide-Xamarin-Binding

Answer (score 3):

Glide is now supported via Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glide.Xamarin/

you can check to use it from here

https://github.com/beraybentesen/glide-xamarin-android/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Glide binding is now supported by Xamarin Team:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Glide/

Repository:
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/Glide